# Xaml radio button checked with specific int value

Tags: xaml

I'm very new to XAML and am trying to make 3 radio buttons (1, 2, 3) in a way so that when I press one of them it changes the value of an int x to its according value

this should explain what I mean

```
<RadioButton Content="{sd:Localize 1, Context=Button}"/> // when checked i want the value of x to become 5
<RadioButton Content="{sd:Localize 2, Context=Button}"/> // when checked i want the value of x to become 6
<RadioButton Content="{sd:Localize 3, Context=Button}"/> // when checked i want the value of x to become 7
```

is there a clean and MVVM-friendly way of achieving this ?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: anyone knows what I should do ?

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this could be:

1. On your Viewmodel add a command to update value of your property X
2. Bind the command to your RadioButton and specify a parameter that will be sent to your command.

   ```
    <RadioButton Command="{Binding UpdateValue}">
      <RadioButton.CommandParameter>
        <system:Int32>1</system:Int32>
      </RadioButton.CommandParameter>
    </RadioButton>
   ```